# How to install an IDE without a graphics environment using a web browser

Tags: windows, docker, ide, localhost, portforwarding

I would like to install PyCharm on an EC2 container running Debian in order to graphically edit and debug code

I get the error "Unable to detect graphics environment"

How does one use a web browser as a GUI (ie port forwarding)

If relevant, my local machine is windows and I connect through docker

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly? What do you hope to accomplish by running an IDE in a docker container? Does that docker container run for you locally? Also, ECS2 isn't a thing. There is EC2, and there is ECS.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You could install it normally, on a Windows EC2 instance. Your local machine's operating system seems irrelevant, the operating system of the EC2 instance is the relevant bit. Also, you should be able to test the docker container locally before even attempting the AWS stuff.